# Can my non-US-resident LLC partner file a 1040NR-EZ?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, limited-liability-company, form-1040x

One of my partners is a non-US-resident.  Our LLC is based in Delaware, and we are subject to pass-through taxation (where we declare our share of profits/losses as income).

In principle, this partner must file a `1040NR`, but in looking at the [instructions for the 1040NR-EZ form](http://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040nre/ar01.html#d0e22), I get the impression that he may be able to file this version instead.

However, I'm a bit perplexed by this passage:

> Your only U.S. source income was from wages, salaries, tips, refunds of state and local income taxes, scholarship or fellowship grants, and nontaxable interest or dividends. 
>   Note. If you had taxable interest or dividend income, you must use Form 1040NR instead of Form 1040NR-EZ.

Does profit from an LLC subject to pass-through taxation count as "wages" or "salaries" as defined in the `1040NR-EZ` form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LLC (partnership) income is reported on Schedule K-1 which flows to Schedule E of the tax return, which can only be filed with the full form 1040/1040NR. So no, your partner cannot file 1040NR-EZ.

Comment: Ah, too bad!  I take it that I can't use the 1040EZ for myself, then, either?  In any case, thank you!

Comment: @blz that's correct.